# Differences between developing custom themes for wordpress.com and wordpress.org?

Tags: theme-development, wordpress.com-hosting

A potential client has asked me to develop a custom theme for their wordpress.com, which you can now do with a business account. I've built a lot of custom themes for the wordpress.org platform. I'm wondering if those themes are compatible with wordpress.com, so long as they meet the requirements of the [wordpress.com theme guide](https://developer.wordpress.com/themes/). Has anyone here developed a custom wordpress.com theme yet?